# compatibility range mismatch between the Web server and database

Tags: restore

On Production Server:
3 tier architecture for Moss2007
Sql server 2008 Enterprise with DB Intranet_Content_Hosted for one of the portals.

On Test Server
3 tier architecture ---3 VM's are created 
SQL server 2008 R2 Enterprise restored the DB Intranet_Content_Hosted
I have created a site collection in MOSS2010.
Now I am trying unattached Content DB from Central Admin of MOSS2010 to restore the Portal.

Under Database name I should give Intranet_Content_Hosted ?Right?
And select Export Site or List ?

Please confirm

Then I select ok and ahead I get the following error............

There is a compatibility range mismatch between the Web server and database "Intranet_Content_Hosted", and connections to the data have been blocked to due to this incompatibility. This can happen when a content database has not been upgraded to be within the compatibility range of the Web server, or if the database has been upgraded to a higher level than the web server. The Web server and the database must be upgraded to the same version and build level to return to compatibility range.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Basically I am trying to restore a site which is in moss2007 into Moss 2010 site collection.
I know there our migration tools out there but i don't want to go that way. Its costly!!!

I thought I should create a clone VM of production server DB SQL2008 and tried to upgrade it to SQL 2008 R2 and take backup of Intranet_Content_Hosted (so that it is compatibile)
Which I can't upgrade too.
Any help is appreciated.
Sucheta

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the unattached contentdb method (which is used only for when the version of the db is the same version of SP that is installed), you will need to use powershell or stsadm to upgrade your database.  See here:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx

I would use this command in powershell if it were me:

```
Mount-SPContentDatabase -Name <DatabaseName> -DatabaseServer <ServerName> -WebApplication <URL> [-Updateuserexperience]
```